# ASP.net Javascript Countdown clock timer for each row of a gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, countdowntimer

Using Asp.net 4.0/C# SQL 2008

I have a page with a gridview on it.  I need a countdown clock in the format HH:MM:SS that will count backwards until it reach the expiration date.  My code is properly showing the clock for the first row of the gridview but any additional rows are not executing the javascript clock.

For testing purposes, I have a basic stored procedure that includes a generic primary key, Expiration date and the Current date.  I call a javascript function that will then get the difference between the 2 dates and format them.  **Appreciate any assistance to help me get the countdown clock timer to appear on each row of the gridview.**

**Current SQL Code:**

```
create proc dbo.tmpdate2 as
begin
select 1 as ElementID, DATEADD(HH,1,GETDATE()) AS ExpDate, getdate() as NowDate
union all
select 2 as ElementID, DATEADD(HH,2,GETDATE()) AS ExpDate, getdate() as NowDate
END
```

**Current ASPX Gridview Code:**

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
    BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Todays Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%# Eval("NowDate")%></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Expiration Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                <label id="ElementID"><label>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    function Countdown(ElementID, ExpDateTimeString, NowDateTimeString) {
                        var NowDateTime = new Date(NowDateTimeString);
                        var ExpDateTime = new Date(ExpDateTimeString);

                        // convert the current date and the target date into miliseconds                       
                        var NowDateTimeMS = (NowDateTime).getTime();
                        var ExpDateTimeMS = (ExpDateTime).getTime();

                        // find their difference, and convert that into seconds                 
                        var TimeLeftSecs = Math.round((ExpDateTimeMS - NowDateTimeMS) / 1000);

                        if (TimeLeftSecs < 0) {
                            TimeLeftSecs = 0;
                        }

                        var Hours = Math.floor(TimeLeftSecs / (60 * 60));
                        TimeLeftSecs %= (60 * 60);
                        var Minutes = Math.floor(TimeLeftSecs / 60);
                        if (Minutes < 10) {
                            Minutes = "0" + Minutes;
                        }
                        TimeLeftSecs %= 60;
                        var Seconds = TimeLeftSecs;
                        if (Seconds < 10) {
                            Seconds = "0" + Seconds;
                        }

                        document.getElementById('ElementID').innerHTML = Hours + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds;

                        // increment the NowDateTime 1 second
                        NowDateTimeMS += 1000;
                        NowDateTime.setTime(NowDateTimeMS);
                        // recursive call, keeps the clock ticking
                        var FunctionCall = "Countdown('" + ElementID + "','" + ExpDateTime + "','" + NowDateTime + "');";
                        setTimeout(FunctionCall, 1000);
                    }
                </script>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                        var NowDateTime = new Date('<%# Eval("NowDate") %>');
                        var ExpDateTime = new Date('<%# Eval("ExpDate") %>');
                        var ElementID = "00:00:00"; 

                        // recursive call, keeps the clock ticking
                        var FunctionCall = "Countdown('" + ElementID + "','" + ExpDateTime + "','" + NowDateTime + "');";
                        setTimeout(FunctionCall, 1000);
                </script>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Current ASPX.CS Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeConnectionString2"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("tmpdate2", thisConnection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(table);

        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a generic method and on each row, you call that method... for example:

your table column should only be:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span id="timer_<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" 
              class="timer" 
              data-start="<%# Eval("EndDate")%>"></span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

then, in your `<script>` block at the end of the page, you should have the timer countdown and fire it for each `.timer` element, like:

*using jQuery to simplify*

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".timer").each(function() {
        var startTime = $(this).data("start");
        Countdown($(this).attr("id"), startTime, new date());
    });
});

function Countdown(ElementID, ExpDateTimeString, NowDateTimeString) { 
    // your countdown...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  In the ItemTemplate block I get the following warning:  Attribute 'data-start' is not a valid attribute of element 'span'.  When executing the app, I get Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined.  Thoughts?

Comment: the warning is ok, you just need to setup Visual Studio to ignore warnings. the `$` I have wrote it down that I was using jQuery, so you will need to add that library if you want to use the code I wrote.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance on this...completely new subject to me.  Do i put everything from the script tag into a .js file?  How do I then call it from the aspx page?

Comment: if you don't even know that, you should give the task to a developer, there are plenty out there that work for very short amount of money, or you can learn from so many tutorials in the internet... my answer is about your current question.